# ¿Como sobreponer elementos con css?

Tags: css, web, diseño

Me explico, estoy haciendo una página web en la cual mi etiqueta NAV la estoy haciendo que este siempre fija cuando navego por la pagina, haciendo que siempre mi menú esté accesible, sin embargo, noto que cuando paso por otros elementos como texto, este se ve por arriba de mi menú, mi etiqueta NAV.

Mi pregunta es: ¿Cómo puedo yo hacer que mi menú pase por arriba de estos elementos? pareciera que mi menú esta por debajo de ellos.

Comment: Sin un [mcve] poco podemos hacer

Comment: Aplica un [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) alto al menú.

Comment: Hola aplica esto en tu etiqueta `nav` desde el `css` `nav {z-index: 9999999999;}`